# Clojure var-defining macro

Tags: macros, clojure

I just learning macros and clojure macros in particular and i'm curious is it possible to do something like this:

```
(defmacro with-a=hello [f]
  `(let [a "hello"] ~f))

(with-a=hello (println a))
```

This not works for me and throws error: `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't let qualified name: user/a, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)`

As i undelstand for now, *scheme*'s *define-syntax* allow to do something like this, but is there clojure way for this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default the syntax-quote form <kbd>`</kbd> prevents introducing un-namespaced symbols and symbol capture in macros. When you intentionally do this you can use the sequence `~'` to introduce an unqualified symbol into a macro.

```
 (defmacro with-a=hello [f]
    `(let [~'a "hello"] ~f))

user> (with-a=hello (println a))
hello
nil
```

macros that do this have the fancy name anaphoric macros

Comment: It's useful to note that `~'` is not any particular special sequence, but just the combination of `~` (leave the syntax-quote) and `'` (begin a normal quote).